# Extend to Palindrome

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In an attempt to solve [UVa 11475 - Extend to Palindrome](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2470)  I came up with the following algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    while (cin >> word) {
        unsigned long i(0), j(word.size() - 1);
        while (i < j) {
            if (word[i] != word[j])
                word.insert(j + 1, 1, word[i]);
            else
                j--;
            i++;
        }
        cout << word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the result is "wrong answer" despite the code giving the right output for the sample input. So what am I missing here? What kind of test case could have caused this?

My professor told us to check the KMP  algorithm, as a hint, but I don't understand what does a string searching algorithm have to do with checking if a string is palindrome.

Answer (score -1):

For example check your program on test

> adbad

It gives wrong answer

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Is there any palindrome string beginning with "adbad" that's shorter than "adbadabda"?

Comment: No, but your programm gives answer adbabda, you can also try aseas, your program output is: aseaesa